# C# parse textual file in a specific format

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have never done something like this so I'm really curious on how this can be performed. I imagine it can be either done via regex or in c# somehow...

I have a textual file with data in following format:

```
12.23.45.56:8080:username:password
12.23.45.56:8080:username:password
12.23.45.56:8080:username:password
12.23.45.56:8080:username:password
```

I have prepared a class which looks like following:

```
public class ParsedData
(
public string IP { get; set; }
public string Port { get; set; }
public string Username { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; } 
)
```

The desired output how I would like it to be is that I can parse each line individually and 1 line should have the data stored in a parsed object (list of ParsedData);

How could do this, and to parse the each line of data individually ?

Can someone help me out ?

```
var completedList = text.Split(':').Select(pr => new ParsedData 
{ 
 IP = pr.ElementAt(0).ToString() // this should be the IP But I'm getting the 
// Index was outside the bounds of the array. exception in this part
/*My elements here*/

}).ToList();
```

Comment: StreamReader, ReadLine, Split

Comment: @Rene I have figured for the split to use like this: text.Split(':').Select(pr => new ParsedData { /*My elements here*/}).ToList(); But what next? XD

Comment: _What next?_ depend on you. Your Linq query is the correct flow to do.

Comment: I'm not going to do the research for you. Enter the keywords in your favorite search engine and plenty of examples should be yours. Report back if you have put something together that doesn't work.

Comment: `.Spit(':')` will return an array containing 4 strings - assign the first to your `IP` property, the 2nd to `Port` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have posted a partial answer till some point ... But I'm getting the Index was outside the bounds of the array. exception

Comment: I'm assuming your calling `.Split()` on a single line. `.Split()` returns an array of `string` and `pr` is each `string` in the collection (using a `.Select()` makes no sense). Just use `var completedList = text.Split(':'); ParsedData data = new ParsedData(){ IP = completedList[0], etc };`

Comment: use this `/(\d{2,3}\.\d{2,3}\.\d{2,3}\.\d{2,3}:\d{4,6}):([\w\d]+):([\w\d]+)/g` regex and the matches index are 1:ip, 2:username, 3:password

Comment: It is strange that until now nobody asked the question: what if `username` or `password` contains a colon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Regex `(.+?):(.+?):(.+?):(.+)`, here example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Main {
    public struct ParsedData {
        public string IP { get; set; }
        public string Port { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; } 
    }
    class Prog {
        static List<ParsedData> pdl = new List<ParsedData>();
        static string file = @"12.23.425.56:90:kukur:psiar%4
151.23.255.52:3131:Zandga:Ikurit
52.23.45.56:5125:Ningame:Mirsga!@
112.223.45.56:4000:Bisgo:One0ne";
        static void Main() {
            var re = new Regex(@"(.+?):(.+?):(.+?):(.+)");
            foreach (Match m in re.Matches(file)) {
                pdl.Add(new ParsedData() { IP = m.Groups[1].Value, Port = m.Groups[2].Value, Username = m.Groups[3].Value, Password = m.Groups[4].Value });
                Console.WriteLine("IP: " + m.Groups[1] + " PORT: " + m.Groups[2] + " USR_NM: " + m.Groups[3] + " PASS: " + m.Groups[4]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also I added an List which contains the data.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like at least one row doesn't have any data in it, maybe there is an empty row in the input data?

Try printing out each row of data before selecting the first element of the array - then you can see which input is causing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //I think you know how to read the file so:
            string text = 
@"12.23.45.56:8080:username:password
12.23.45.56:8080:username:password
12.23.45.56:8080:username:password
12.23.45.56:8080:username:password";

            List<ParsedData> ps = new List<ParsedData>();

            text.Split(new char[] { '\r','\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList().ForEach(c =>
             {
                 var cols = c.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```

//you can check too if cols have content here

```
                 ps.Add(new ParsedData()
                 {
                     IP = cols[0]!=null?cols[0]:"", //and check if inside it's content..
                     Port = cols[1],
                     Username = cols[2],
                     Password = cols[3]
                 });
             });

            foreach(ParsedData p in ps)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.IP + "\t" + p.Port + "\t" + p.Username + "\t" + p.Password);
            }

        }
    }
    public class ParsedData
    {
        public string IP { get; set; }
        public string Port { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you make misunderstood about the pr, it not array now, it the element in the array.

```
var text = "12.23.45.56:8080:username:password";
var array = text.Split(':');
var data = new ParsedData()
       {
           IP = array[0],
           Port = array[1],
           Username = array[2],
           Password = array[3]
       };
```

Comment: Except that you would first check that the array contain 4 elements